# Grant users access to mysql with a dash in the database name

Tags: mysql, permissions

Unfortunately, I have a database name with a dash in it.
How do I grant access to that database as mysql reports a syntax error.

e.g.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON astpp.* TO 'portal'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'Ab7g12Xh35' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

works, but

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON astpp-eth01.* TO 'portal'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'Ab7g12Xh35' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Does not.

Neither does:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON 'astpp-eth01'.* TO 'portal'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'Ab7g12Xh35' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On mysql you escape database column names with the backtick character unless you have ANSI_QUOTES enabled.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html.

Try using a command like this.

```
grant select,insert,update,delete on `astpp-eth01`.* to 'portal'@'localhost' identified by 'Ab7g12Xh35' with grant option;
```